# How to make a non-indented, monospaced Chinese character layout

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, chinese

I want the text to be laid out exactly as it appears here in the monospaced code environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{font.otf}
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{111111}
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\textcolor{light}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

...

\begin{verbatim}
```

How do I do this? Right now it's giving me indents for every new block, and the newlines within each block don't work (I would need to add `\\` or `\newline` everywhere). How can I leave it as is and get it to render without indents and with new lines?

It would also be nice to know how to set the font size of the Chinese characters. I am using the CJK Noto font.

Comment: `\obeylines` will get you partway there, and `\vspace{\baselineskip}` at the beginning and end of the `\cc` command. `poetry` and `verse` packages show the extent of the constraints and solutions when emulating blank lines. `fancyvrb` package might provide some ideas. Package `xeCJK` could be helpful later. `[Scale=1.5]` option when setting the font, or the usual `\small`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\huge` etc relative size commands are two ways to affect font size.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `\parindent` to 0pt would take away the documentclass indentation, but assuming you don't want to use the standard heading commands (like `\section` etc) with all their associated spacings etc needing adjustment, the `alltt` package could help.

By way of intro, the `verbatim` environment prints things exactly as it sees them:

[image: verbatim view]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}%font.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{111199}
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\textcolor{light}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；
\end{verbatim}
%\end{poem}
%\end{Verbatim}
%\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The `alltt` environment does a `verbatim`, but allows `\`, `{` and `}` to have their usual command/parameter affect:

[image: alltt environment]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}%font.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\definecolor{light}{HTML}{111199}
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\textcolor{light}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{alltt}
\begin{alltt}
\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

If we modify the `\cc` command a touch, as if it were going to function almost like a `\section` heading command:

[image: large blue heading]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}%font.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\definecolor{light}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\newcommand\cc[1]{{\Large\color{light}\bfseries #1}}
\begin{document}
\section{alltt}
\begin{alltt}
\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章} 

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；

\cc{第一章}

道可道，非恆道
名可名，非恆名。
無名天地之始；
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

How-to:

`alltt` (= all in teletype font = typewriter font = mono-spaced font; at least, in intention) -- if we set the `\ttfamily` font to the CJK one, with `\setmonofont{Noto Serif CJK SC}`, say, `alltt` will apply the font. Technically it's not a typewriter font, but CJK characters are by design 'mono-spaced'.

Short lines of text will be OK.